# What should I change for optimize the replace method?

Tags: java, replace

I'm creating a method to know how many time there are 'RAV' inside a string.
My program works, but it should be faster when the string has +10.000 characters.

First I used String, then StringBuilder and it's faster but not enough.

```
public class E{

    private static int replace(String cad){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cad);
        int cont = 0;
        while (sb.indexOf("RAV") > -1 && cont < 50000) {
            sb.replace(sb.indexOf("RAV"), sb.indexOf("RAV") + 3, "");
            cont++;
        }
        return cont;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[]{"RARAVV", "VAR", "RAVV"};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(replace(arr[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is

```
2
0
1
```

Comment: "it's faster but not enough" Oh so you've profiled it then? And what were your exact results?

Comment: Don't do any replacements in the string. Instead use this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

Comment: For starters, you would be better off not calling `sb.indexOf("RAV")` 3 times in the same loop iteration... Just store the result.

Comment: i would use `recursion` here instead of that crazy `while`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't actually return the replaced string. The replace function returns the count. Is that intentional? What is the point of the (cont < 50000) condition? Is it required?

Comment: @Michael - do you need to profile it to tell that its slow? Seems obvious to me.

Comment: @rghome I expect anyone who is concerned with performance to have researched how to actually measure performance, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on a linear algorithm. Not the most general or beautiful code but it shows the idea.
Only a single scan is made through the string and we don't look back or forward, which gives an effort linear in the length of the string.

For longer strings this should be significantly faster than the "replace" based algorithms.

```
public class Main {

    private static class StateFrame {
        int matched;
        StateFrame previous;
    }

    private static int count(String cad) {
        StateFrame state = new StateFrame();
        final int len = cad.length();
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            final char ch = cad.charAt(i);
            if (ch == 'R') {
                if (state.matched == 0) {
                    state.matched = 1;
                } else {
                    StateFrame next = new StateFrame();
                    next.previous = state;
                    state = next;
                    state.matched = 1;
                }
            } else if (ch == 'A') {
                if (state.matched == 1) {
                    state.matched = 2;
                } else {
                    state.previous = null;
                    state.matched = 0;
                }
            } else if (ch == 'V') {
                if (state.matched == 2) {
                    result++;
                    if (state.previous == null) {
                        state.matched = 0;
                    } else {
                        state = state.previous;
                    }
                } else {
                    state.previous = null;
                    state.matched = 0;
                }
            } else {
                state.previous = null;
                state.matched = 0;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[] { "RARAVV", "VAR", "RAVV", "RRAVRXXXAV", "RARRAVAVV", "RRAVARAVV", "RRARAVVARAVV" };
        for (String anArr : arr) {
            System.out.printf("%s %d%n", anArr, count(anArr));
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an output of

```
RARAVV 2
VAR 0
RAVV 1
RRAVRXXXAV 1
RARRAVAVV 3
RRAVARAVV 3
RRARAVVARAVV 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private static int replace(String cad) {
    int originalLength = cad.length();
    for (;;) {
        String cad2 = cad.replace("RAV", "");
        if (cad2.length() == cad.length()) {
            break;
        }
        cad = cad2;
    }
    return (originalLength - cad.length()) / "RAV".length();
}
```

First of all `indexOf` should be put into a variable as three times used.
`String.replace` can do multiple replaces. The expression reduction then has a different order, but for "RAV" that will not yield a different result.

In the above you could test the replace result for `cad2 == cad` but some style checkers will prefer an equals. Length equality suffices.

And of course the number of replacements is the length reduction / 3.

---

***As actual measurement showed `String.replace(String, String)` to be slow:***

```
private static int replace(String cad) {
    // Could try to shorten string: cad = cad.replaceAll("[^RAV]+", "e");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cad);
    int pos0 = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int pos = sb.indexOf("RAV", pos0);
        if (pos == -1) {
            break;
        }
        sb.delete(pos, pos + 3);
        // Continue searching 2 chars before.
        pos0 = Math.max(0, pos - 2); // RA[RAV]V
    }
    return (cad.length() - sb.length()) / 3;
}
```

Thanks goes to @GPI for even benchmarking.

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, this is actually slower in my quick tests (JMH with 10 randomStrings of length 200 to 5000, with 0 to 10 occurences of RAV). After a first inspection, I strongly suspect it's because String.replace uses the regexp engine, which is obviously slower than exact char[] matching (could be enhanced by compiling the pattern once and for all).

Comment: @GPI **interesting** - thanks. AFAIK indeed the regex replace is used, but with a non-regex switch `Pattern.LITERAL`, and a quoted "RAV". So one could make a better replace implementation. For the problem at hand maybe using a Pattern outside the loop.

Comment: I've just thrown a basic loop at the code, and JMC's profiler tells me 94% of CPU time is spent in Matcher.find() with this implementation. 4% in the appending, and compilation is too low to have an accurate idea (~0.2%). YMMV on shorter strings, or different level of nestings.

Comment: @GPI added an "optimized" `indexOf`  version. `max` might be a bit slow.

Comment: Also `cad = cad.replaceAll("[^RAV]+", "e");` might be interesting, though I do not think it will help.

Comment: the indexOf/delete/max looks like a real win in my JMH scenario. OP's version is at 1700 ops/s, OP's with caching is at 4000, and your last code is at 11500. It's obvious advantage is not to start from scratch each time.

Answer (score 1):

> First I used String, then StringBuilder and it's faster

Are you sure? What test cases did you use?
For this:

```
RAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAV
```

do you think that a `StringBuilder` is faster than a `String`?
Consider this method:

```
public static int replace(String cad, String pattern){
    String str = cad;
    do {
        str = str.replace(pattern, "");
    } while (str.contains(pattern));
    return (cad.length() - str.length()) / pattern.length();
}
```

This version of `replace()` is surely **much faster** than yours in test cases like the above mentioned `String` and for the majority of random test cases as it can make more than 1 replacements in 1 iteration and does not use any counter.  
A `StringBuilder` would be more efficient and faster when you deal with cases like:

```
RARARARARARARARARARAVVVVVVVVVV
```

Comment: I do agree that there may not be a "better implementation" regardless of the real world usage (e.g. typical number of "nesting", typical number of occurences). Nonetheless, `String.replace` has a real high upfront (regexp compilation) and execution cost (regexp engine) that makes me think that a char iteration based process might be the way to go. Case in point, with a JMH test for "RAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAVRAV", the OP's implementation has twice the throughput of this (2329416 op/s vs 1076182), that without even caching the `indexOf()` call in the original implementation.

Comment: `String.replace` has nothing to do with **regexp**. Maybe you mean `replaceAll` which is not the case.

Comment: In my JDK8 at hand, String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement), line 2238, is implemented by regexp. `return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
                this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()))`. Although a literal one.

Comment: Indeed it is!! never seen (or cared) before.

Comment: I'm thinking *a char iteration based process might be the way to go* would complicate this process wouldn't it? Keeping things simple and efficient.

Comment: I usually use commons-lang replace implementations for pure char based implementations. So far, the best complexity / speed ratio I've tested is to optimize the OP's code with caching of indexOf calls. I do agree that counting chars around might be a code-mess for little improvements.

Comment: Also, this is not a simple replace case. This involves reiterating after every scan for cases like "RARAVV".

Answer (score 0):

If you make this with `recursion` it would be much faster.

```
public class E{

    private int cont;

    private static int replace(String cad){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cad);

        if(sb.indexOf("RAV") > -1){
            sb.replace(sb.indexOf("RAV"), sb.indexOf("RAV") + 3, "");
            cont++;
            return replace(sb.toString())}
        else{
            return cont; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cont = 0;
        String[] arr = new String[]{"RARAVV", "VAR", "RAVV"};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(replace(arr[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is everybody locked into this hopelessly inefficient "replace" approach? The original problem is just about counting.

Comment: @Henry the way I understand it (it's not that clear), is that if you input "AAABBB" and the pattern to search for is "AB", then the function should return 3 (if you remove it once, you get AABB, which contains AB, and once removed, you still have one AB). **If** I'm correct in this interpretation, then replacing is one obvious way to "count".

Comment: @GPI after carefully reading the question again, it seems you are right with this interpretation. Still, I have the feeling a linear algorithm (using a stack) is possible.

Comment: @GPI I have put the idea of a linear algorithm now into code and added an answer.